# Infinite Series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^nn}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Just encountered a problem in my BC Calculus sequences and series unit that I just can't figure out.

I don't know the latex, but the problem was to find compute 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^nn}
$$
The handout was just on convergence, so it was easy to see that by ratio test, it does converge, but I think I'm missing some ideas to be able to calculate the sum.

We have done Taylor series, I just don't quite know how to go backwards, although my guess is that you find a way to write the partial sums and find it's value as the limit approaches infinity.

How would you go about solving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: What function has a Taylor series resembling $\sum x^n/n$?

Comment: e^x is close to that with $\sum x^n/n!$.

Comment: Hint: what if you differentiated $\sum x^n/n$? What series do you get?

Comment: sum x^(n-1) right?

Comment: No, I left out the factorial. No factorials.

Comment: Ahh, got it. It's the sum of x^(n-1), which can easily be computed, so just integrate 1/(1-x) and make x=1/2. That makes a lot of sense, thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}, $ for $|x|<1$. Geometric series.

Integrate both sides to get

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n} = C-\ln (1-x), $ for $|x|<1$.

For $x=0$ you see that $C=0$. Then substitute $x=1/2$ to get $\ln 2$

The integration is valid for any closed interval $[-a,a]$ for $a \in [0,1)$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you so much. As a follow up, the sum of 1/(2^n*n!) was also asked on this handout. What would be your approach? Integrals seem pretty tricky with factorials.

Comment: In this case the series is $e^{1/2}$. You have to know the Taylor series for some basic functions.

Comment: Also, substituting x=1/2 means the sum = -ln(1/2), which according to WolframAlpha should be ln(2). Thoughts?

Comment: I wrote the same.

Comment: How did you get ln(2)?

Comment: $-\ln(1-\frac{1}{2})=-\ln (\frac{1}{2})=-\ln (2^{-1})=-(-1)\ln (2) = \ln (2).$